# redirecting itemchecked to a new activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have read and tried to follow some other threads from stackoverflow and I am not understanding how to get this to work.

Brief description.  I have an activity that loads the contact list into a custom list view.  I can select the contacts using a check box.  I also have a done button and a cancel button.  When the done button is selected it will take all the check box items and display the contacts in a new activity with its own custom list view.

My issue is how to set up my button click to display just the selected contacts.

here is my done button code very rough:

```
     private Button mDoneButton, mCancelButton;

ListView guestListView;
ProgressDialog guestProgressDialog;
ArrayList<String> guestAA = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> guestNum = new ArrayList<String>();
//ArrayList<String> guestEmail = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.contacts);

    guestListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            guestProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(contactDisplayActivity.this, "Loading...", "Please Wait", true, false);
        } //end of on PreExecute method

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            getGuestContacts();

            return null;
        } //end of doInBackground method

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //getGuestContacts();
            guestProgressDialog.dismiss();
            CustomAdapter guestCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(contactDisplayActivity.this);
            guestListView.setAdapter(guestCustomAdapter);
        } //end of onPostExecute Method
    } .execute((Void[]) null);

    //Done Button
    mDoneButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
    mDoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long [] guestIds = guestListView.getCheckedItemIds();
            for (long guestId : guestIds ) {
                getGuestContacts();

            }
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(contactDisplayActivity.this, GuestList.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

    //Cancel Button
    mCancelButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    mCancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //mListener.onFragmentInteraction();
            //((PlanMeMainActivity) getActivity()).newActivityToLaunch(1);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(contactDisplayActivity.this, EventDetails.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}

private void getGuestContacts() {
    ContentResolver guestContactResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor guestCursor = guestContactResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (guestCursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (guestCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String guestId = guestCursor.getString(guestCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String guestName = guestCursor.getString(guestCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            //String guestEmail = guestCursor.getString(guestCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));

            guestAA.add(guestName);


            if (Integer.parseInt(guestCursor.getString(guestCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor phoneCursor = guestContactResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{guestId}, null);

                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    guestNum.add(phoneNumber);
                }

                //while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                  //  String email = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
                    //guestEmail.add(email);
                //}
                phoneCursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

}

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return guestNum.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        final int pos = position;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.contacts_display, null);

            holder.textviewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactsTextView1);
            holder.textviewNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactsTextView2);
            //holder.textViewEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactsTextView3);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactsCheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.textviewName.setId(position);
        holder.textviewNumber.setId(position);
        //holder.textViewEmail.setId(position);

        holder.textviewName.setText(guestAA.get(position));
        holder.textviewNumber.setText("No. " + guestNum.get(position));
        //holder.textViewEmail.setText(guestEmail.get(position));

        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textviewName;
    TextView textviewNumber;
    //TextView textViewEmail;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int id;

}

}
```

the getGuestContacts method displays the contact list.

Any help or direction would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: So you want the selected contacts to be shown in the `GuestList` or you want to update the list you already have at `contactDisplayActivity`??

Comment: I want the selected contacts to show up in Guest list. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the entire class? If it's to big then just the local variables, onCreate(), and getGuestContacts()

Comment: i have added the full class. thanks

Comment: I don't see where you add the contacts to `guestCustomAdapter` to populate the List. This approach is way different than how i would have made it.

Comment: what would you recommend. I am new to android and I still learning.  Thanks.